# Sonata admin: mosaic selected by default

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata, symfony-sonata

I am using Sonata Admin and I have a list and a mosaic view.
How to select the mosaic view by default?
I do not want to HIDE the list view, just select the mosaic view by default.

Answer (score 4):

The Admin classes inherit from `AbstractAdmin`. If we have an Entity class `Foo`, we would create an Admin class `FooAdmin` extending `Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin`.

Let's take a look into the source code:

```
public function setListMode($mode)
{
    if (!$this->hasRequest()) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('No request attached to the current admin: %s', $this->getCode()));
    }

    $this->getRequest()->getSession()->set(sprintf('%s.list_mode', $this->getCode()), $mode);
}

public function getListMode()
{
    if (!$this->hasRequest()) {
        return 'list';
    }

    return $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get(sprintf('%s.list_mode', $this->getCode()), 'list');
}
```

These are the methods that set and get the list mode. There are buttons for two list modes: `list` and `mosaic`. If you hover with the mouse pointer you'll see that they point to the same URL, but with different parameters:

- /list?_list_mode=list
- /list?_list_mode=mosaic

In the method `getListMode` we see that the `list` mode is called per default.

The way I found out to set `mosaic` as default is to call the method `setListMode` in the Admin class:

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    if ($mode = $this->request->query->get('_list_mode')) {
        $this->setListMode($mode);
    } else {
        $this->setListMode('mosaic');
    }

    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('fooId')
        ->add('fooBar')
    ;
}
```

I hope it can help someone. I was looking for more elegant ways, like setting in the admin service, but couldn't find a better solution. If someone has other suggestions, I'd be happy to learn something new.

Comment: This solution will fail if there's no request, for example as a result of a global search. I would suggest to simply do:         if ($this->hasRequest()) {
            $this->setListMode('mosaic');
        }

Comment: @devilcius I didn't think of that edge case.Thank you for pointing out. For me it did work this way. I think an ideal solution would be to set the option in the admin service, but I don't know how to do it. Any fiddling in the method `configureListFields` is a dirty approach.

Comment: @devilcius The problem with your solution would be that the mosaic view will be shown, even if the user clicks on the list button. That would be irritating. The if condition should be expanded with your snippet, in order to catch the edge case you mentioned. It is however still a quick-and-dirty solution and I'm aware of that, but in lack of deeper understanding and better knowledge I have to stick with it for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

> In the method getListMode we see that the list mode is called per
>   default.

So in my opinion the simplest way is to override `getListMode` and to replace 'list' by 'mosaic'.

```
public function getListMode()
{
    if (!$this->hasRequest()) {
        return 'mosaic';
    }

    return $this->getRequest()->getSession()->get(sprintf('%s.list_mode', $this->getCode()), 'mosaic');
}
```